# How to Prevent sliding in 2d movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi i want to move my charachter i looked around but couldnt find solutions for my code i just want when my charachter moves and i not pressed move forward button then it stop but not instantly it just stops instantly after i unpressed d button here is my code

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    bool ismoving;
    public float speed = 5f;
    

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        {
            ismoving = true;
        }
        else { ismoving = false; }

        if (ismoving)
        {
            
            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime *10);
        }
        else 
        { 
         while((rb2d.velocity) != (rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero))
            {
                rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime *-1);                
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the multiplier for your deceleration to a greater value

```
while((rb2d.velocity) != (rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero))
    {
        rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * -10);                
    }
```

Now it should decelerate 10 times faster than before

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you stop adding force when the key is released. How about approaching a speed of 0 once the key is released? Like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    bool ismoving;
    public float maxspeed = 5f;
    private float currentSpeed = 0f;
    private float movingDirection = 0f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        {
            ismoving = true;
            movingDirection = horizontal;
        }
        else 
        {
            ismoving = false; 
            // keep the movingDirection as it is.
        }

        if (ismoving)
        {
            // accelerate
            currentSpeed += 5 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            currentSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(currentSpeed, 0, maxspeed); 
        }
        else 
        {
            currentSpeed -= 5 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            currentSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(currentSpeed, 0, maxspeed);
            // also fake some friction
            rb2d.velocity = rb2d.velocity * 0.96f;
        }
        // always apply the force, it may be 0 though.
        rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(movingDirection, 0) * currentSpeed;
    }
}
```

Maybe it works better when setting velocity instead of adding force with this approach. But you may get the point: Instead of instantly stopping to add force when the key is released, we simply decrease a variable `currentspeed` and continue to work with that until we stop. Since `horizontal` is getting 0 quickly after releasing the key, I added a helper variable to remember the direction we *were* going before releasing the key called `movingDirection`.

Also a nice-to-know tip: Try to do all `Input...` Calls in `Update()`, save states in variables that you then use in `FixedUpdate()`. Because otherwise, you may run into problems, when things like `Input.GetButtonDown()` is true for 2-3 FixedUpdate Calls, but you want things to happen **once** per click/press like shooting.